# Mudar o iframe (embed bootstrap) de acordo com o botão da barra de navegação

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

Exemplo:

Navegação:

```
   <ul >
    <li><a href="#"><span>INICIO</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>FACEBOOK</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>STACKOVERFLOW</span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

Embed:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="index.php"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="www.facebook.com.br"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://pt.stackoverflow.com/"></iframe>
</div>
```

O que preciso:

Sempre iniciar com o frame inicial `index.php` quando a pessoa clicar no menu em `facebook`, abrir o frame `facebook` e assim por diante

Comment: Você está usando jquery?

Comment: o que você já tentou fazer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você também pode usar o mesmo frame, trocando o destino dele.

O frame precisa ter um **name** para poder ser referenciado.
Neste exemplo coloquei **name="meuframe"**

```
<iframe name="meuframe" src="http://terra.com.br"></iframe>
```

Os links devem ter como **target** o nome do frame:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://uol.com.br" target="meuframe"><span>UOL</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://binds.co" target="meuframe"><span>Binds.co</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="http://codepen.io" target="meuframe"><span>Codepen</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Dessa forma, o frame carrega com seu **src** normal, e os links têm como alvo, o frame, alterando sua origem.

Veja funcionando: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NROzJd?editors=1000

Answer (score 1):

Veja este este exemplo te ajuda:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <meta name="keywords" content="jquery,ui,easy,easyui,web">
 <meta name="description" content="easyui help you build your web page easily!">
 <title>jQuery EasyUI Demo</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  function addTab(title, url){
   if ($('#tt').tabs('exists', title)){
    $('#tt').tabs('select', title);
   } else {
    var content = '<iframe scrolling="auto" frameborder="0"  src="'+url+'" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>';
    $('#tt').tabs('add',{
     title:title,
     content:content,
     closable:true
    });
   }
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div style="margin-bottom:10px">
  <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="addTab('google','http://www.google.com')">google</a>
  <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="addTab('jquery','http://jquery.com/')">jquery</a>
  <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="addTab('easyui','http://jeasyui.com/')">easyui</a>
 </div>
 <div id="tt" class="easyui-tabs" style="width:400px;height:250px;">
  <div title="Home">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Link do exemplo](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/layout/tabs2.php)

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra forma também de fazer:

```js
var iframe = $(".embed-responsive-item");

$("#menu li a").click(function() {
  iframe.attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#" data-src="index.php"><span>INICIO</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-src="www.facebook.com.br"><span>FACEBOOK</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-src="http://pt.stackoverflow.com"><span>STACKOVERFLOW</span></a></li>
</ul>

<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="index.php"></iframe>
</div>
```